# How does one color the INPUT text in the console for a PERL program being run in a Macintosh terminal session?

Tags: perl, colors

Not sure how to do this, but I've go a program that every time I run I have to enter in two data points, and they are hard to find in the console--squinting and so on. Is there a way to colorize the INPUT, so while I'm looping through the program repetitively (putting these tuples in and so on) I can keep track of where I am from the last program run. I'd like it to be whatever color is the inverted color of lime green--I'm in "Invert colors" mode now.

---

What I'd like to achieve is a colorization that colorizes as I type input in--you know, an input stream colorization or something.

---

```
print "Enter where you'd like me to begin: ";
my $begin = <STDIN>;
chomp $begin;
exit 0 if ($begin eq "");
print "\n";
print "Enter where you'd like me to end: ";
my $end = <STDIN>;
chomp $end;
exit 0 if ($end eq "");
print "\n";
```

Comment: Depends on the console used to run the perl program....

Comment: What do you mean? I'm just running it in the command line; that is, the terminal on a Macintosh. Perhaps I don't understand your comment.

Comment: check out http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html

Comment: Interesting, can this work if I'm trying to colorize my input? Like, `<STDIN>`... Guess there is only one way to find out... Well, just tried it, that doesn't work. At least, the way I implemented it.

Comment: @user3333975 can you post some code you're working with and some example input/output and which part you want colorized?

Comment: @Matt, yes, hold on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl programs echo the `STDIN` as you type it. Since you want to colorize only what is typed in, you'll have to capture it and then print it with color. I modified your program to show how to do this.

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use Term::ReadKey;

ReadMode('noecho'); # don't echo

print "Enter where you want me to begin: ";
my $begin = <STDIN>;
chomp $begin;
exit 0 if ($begin eq "");
print colored("$begin\n", 'red');
print "Enter where you'd like me to end: ";
my $end = <STDIN>;
chomp $end;
exit 0 if ($end eq "");
print colored("$end\n", 'red');

ReadMode(0);        # back to normal
```

Example output:

> Enter where you want me to begin: 1
>   Enter where you'd like me to end: 2

(The 1 and 2 are in red)

Red is the inverse of green, so that's why I picked it since you're running in inverse color mode on your console. You could also try bright_red if that's not close enough to lime green as you'd like.

Here is the documentation for  [Term::ANSIColor](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html) and [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TermReadKey/ReadKey.pm)